# Triban RC 100 upgrade

Tags: shimano, gravel, tiagra

I hope you're all safe.
I'm looking to upgrade my Triban rc 100.
It includes Shimano Touney groupset and Microshift x7 cassette.
Currently, the groupset that attracts me the most is the Shimano Tiagra 4700 2 or 3x10 and a compatible back wheel.
However, I'm want to ensure that I can mount this groupset on my bike.
Therefore, I would like to know if this groupset would be compatible with my bike frame.
Could someone please help in discovering this, as well as other considerations I have to take into account before upgrading?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapping out a groupset on a rim brake road bike is pretty straightforward as most components can simple be replaced.

In your case there are a few special considerations.

You correctly identified that you may need to replace the rear wheel. This is because you either have a 7 speed freewheel type hub or a freehub tyoe with a narrower 7 speed freehub body. However, you possibly have a 8/9/10 speed freehub, and a spacer behind the 7 speed cassette. if this is the case you will not need a new wheel. The [2020 RC100](https://www.decathlon.co.uk/rc100-road-bike-grey-id_8554266.html) page does not specify what hub is used.

Thee RC100 does not have a front derailleur, so the frame may lack mounting points for front derailleur cables and routing through the bottom bracket area. A clamp-on style derailleur mount will be necessary of course.

You'll need to replace the bottom bracket along wth the crank. It's very likely the crank is a three-piece with square table axle. You could find a double or triple crank that (probably Claris or Sora) that is square taper, but the axle length would probably be incorrect for the different cranks.

Rim brake groupsets are relatively cheap these days, but bear in mind that it will still be a significant cost compared to the original proce of the bike, especially of you have to replace the rear wheel. Also. you'll still have the heavier lower-level frame and other components. Another option to consider is a new Claris or Sora equipped bike, so you get an upgrade of all the components.

Comment: So would it be a good idea to buy a new one that already has the groupset I want, perhaps this one: https://www.fr.bikester.be/983657.html ?

Comment: @Greg86 Yes, that's what I generally recommend, you get a fully upgraded bike that works immediately, don't have to spend time assembling and adjusting, don't have to buy some special tools etc. Link is broken btw

Answer (score 1):

It should be quite possible. Even the rear wheel hub might work as is if it really is a cassette (most likely CS-H072 12-28) and not a freewheel. You will also need a new bottom bracket with the new chainset. You may decide whether to keep the brakes or not, it is possible.

Overall it will not be cheap and you will have a cheap frame with a good groupset and potentially cheap wheels. It is up to each individual to decide whther it is worth the investment. Cheaper groupsets, like Sora and Claris are also decent, but have less speeds. Again, up to everyone's individual decision. The no-longer needed components can be sold, but will not be worth that much.

I would suggest to think twice about the 3x cranks. They are not very popular today, because modern modern gearings allow wide range of gears with 2x cranks. The difference between those two chainrings is now most often 16 and that is more than it traditionally used to be. With 10x speeds in the rear the spacing still should be good enough even though modern rear derailleurs allow cassettes with a wider gear range.